# Enforcing "style" rules in JSON Schema files?

Tags: json, coding-style, naming-conventions, jsonschema

I am looking at using [JSON Schemas](http://json-schema.org/) for an upcoming project, and looking for a way to validate our naming conventions/style and consistency rules in the JSON Schema file.  Somewhat similar to [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) or [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/).

Using this samples from [JSON Schema Lint](http://jsonschemalint.com/) to illustrate:

```
{
    "description": "Any validation failures are shown in the right-hand Messages pane.", 
    "type": "object", 
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "number"
        }, 
        "bar": {
            "type": "string", 
            "enum": [
                "a", 
                "b", 
                "c"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Imagine another developer wants to add a new property, but I want to prevent property names from being upper-case (`baz` instead of `Baz`) or maybe `boolean` properties should start with "is" (`isBaz`).  Is there a way to "unit test" the JSON Schema file and check for that?

```
"Baz": {
    "type": "boolean"
},
```

It feels like a custom validator for the JSON Schema file (vs. using the JSON Schema to validate the JSON output).  Does something like that already exist, or do I just parse the JSON schema file myself and write the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely possible to write a meta-schema that enforces this constraint on your schemas.  Let's construct  it step-by-step:

### 1. Constraining property names

The key part is to use `patternProperties` to specify which property names are allowed, and `additionalProperties` to disallow anything else:

```
{
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]*)*$": {}
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

*(For this example, I've used the regex `^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]*)*$` to detect alphabetic-only lowerCamelCase)*

Note that it doesn't matter whether provide any constraints for suitably-named properties (here it's just the empty schema `{}`).  However, the presence of this definition means that any matching property is allowed, while anything else is banned by `additionalProperties`.

#### Fancier constraints

For other constraints (such as your "boolean properties must start with `is`" one), you just add more complex entries here.

This answer focuses more on how to make a generic recursive naming-style schema.  It's already pretty long, so if you're looking for guidance on how to express a specific constraint, then it might be neater to ask as a separate question.

### 2. Applying to the `properties` property

This bit's pretty simple - make these constraints apply to the appropriate part of the schema:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "properties": {"$ref": "#/definitions/propertyStyleRule"}
    },
    "definitions": {
        "propertyStyleRule": {
            "patternProperties": {
                "^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]*)*$": {}
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Make it recursive

In fact, you don't just want to cover sub-schemas inside `"properties"`, but also `"items"`, `"anyOf"`, etc.

Here it gets quite long, so I'll omit most of it, but basically you go through every keyword that might contain a schema, and make sure they are subject to the same naming-scheme by referencing the root schema:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "properties": {"$ref": "#/definitions/propertyStyleRule"},

        "additionalProperties": {"$ref": "#"},
        "items": {"$ref": "#"},
        "not": {"$ref": "#"},
        "allOf": {"$ref": "#"},
        ...
    },
    "definitions": {
        "propertyStyleRule": {
            "patternProperties": {
                "^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]*)*$": {"$ref": "#"}
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** we've also now replaced the empty schema (`{}`) in our `"propertyStyleRule"` definition with a reference back to the root (`{"$ref": "#"}`), so the sub-schemas inside `properties` also recurse properly.

### 4. Hang on, some of those keywords can be arrays, or booleans, or...

OK, so there's an obvious problem here: `"not"` holds a schema, so that's fine, but `"allOf"` holds an array of schemas, `"items"` can hold either, and `"additionalProperties"` can be a boolean.

We could do some fancy switching with different types, ***or*** we could simply add an `items` entry to our root schema:

```
{
    "items": {"$ref": "#"},
    "properties": {
        ...
    },
    "definitions": {
        "propertyStyleRule": {...}
    }
}
```

Because we haven't specified a `type`, our root schema actually allows instances to be objects/arrays/boolean/string/whatever - and if the instance isn't an object, then `properties` is just ignored.

Similarly, `items` is ignored unless the instance is an array - but if it *is* an array, then the entries must also follow the root schema.  So it doesn't matter whether the value of `"items"` is a schema or an array of schemas, it recurses properly either way.

## 5. Schema maps

For a few keywords (like `"patternProperties"` or `"definitions"`) the value is not a schema, it's a map of strings to schemas, so you can't just reference the root schema.  For these, we'll make a definition `"schemaMap"`, and reference that instead:

```
{
    "items": {"$ref": "#"},
    "properties": {
        "properties": {"$ref": "#/definitions/propertyStyleRule"},

        "additionalProperties": {"$ref": "#"},
        "items": {"$ref": "#"},
        "not": {"$ref": "#"},
        "allOf": {"$ref": "#"},
        ...
        "patternProperties": {"$ref": "#/definitions/schemaMap"},
        ...
    },
    "definitions": {
        "schemaMap": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {"$ref": "#"}
        },
        "propertyStyleRule": {...}
    }
}
```

... and you're done!

I've left out details, but hopefully it's clear enough how to write the full version.

Also, once you've written this once, it should be pretty easy to adapt it for different style rules, or even applying similar constraints to the names in `"definitions"`, etc.  If you do write a schema like this, please consider posting it somewhere so that other people can adapt it! :)